# RegExp only allowing strings not containing a set of prefixes

Tags: .net, regex, string, validation

I couldn't find any questions similar to this, so here it goes.

I need a Regular Expression that will validate a phone number. So first and foremost only numbers, dashes and a '+' is allowed.

The difficult part is allowing only expressions that start with any of the strings from the following set:

```
50  
51  
53  
57  
60  
66  
69  
72  
73  
78  
79  
88
```

Any other numbers without those prefixes should not be allowed.

I'll be extremely grateful for any tips! Thanks!

Comment: Regular expressions differs in different programs. Grep and sed has it's own regexps, python has its own, perl has its own and so on. Which programming language you are using?

Comment: I am sorry, I was not aware of that. I need this expression for .NET WebForms 3.5 Validation Controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix part is quite simple. `^` is an anchor, that represents the start of the string. Then just append your desired pattern (I believe you want to allow the plus as the first character):

```
^\+?(?:50|51|53|57|60|66|69|72|73|78|79|88)[\d-]+$
```

Note that the `$` is the counterpart to `^` and ensures that your string does not contain non-digit non-dash characters after the phone number.

Of course the pattern at the end can be made a lot more specific to disallow consecutive dashes and such things.

Also note that `\d` in .NET matches any Unicode digit character. If that is not what you desire, use `[0-9-]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak this, but here's a start:

```
^(50|51|53|57|60|66|69|72|73|78|79|88)\d+$
                                       ^
                                       |
                                       -----This part probably needs 
                                            more constraints, depending on 
                                            your format
```